# Some hypersurface has a positive second fundamental form potentially

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Notation : $r^2=x^2+y^2$.

Exercise : Define $$F_\sigma (x,y)= (f_\sigma
(x,y),\frac{x^2-y^2}{2},xy)$$ where $$f_\sigma (x,y)=(1- \sigma^2
r^2)(x-\sigma x^3,y-\sigma y^3)$$

Define $ G_\sigma: \mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow
\mathbb{R}^4$ by
$$G_\sigma(x,y,a,b)=(dF_\sigma )_{(x,y)} (a,b)  =(
 (df_\sigma)_{(x,y)}(a,b) ,R(x,y))$$ where $R$ is $\angle ((a,b),(1,0))$-rotation

Then there is a sequence of balls $U_\sigma$ and unit circle $S$
s.t. $\lim_{\sigma\rightarrow 0}\ {\rm diam}\ U_\sigma =0$ and
$G_\sigma (U_\sigma \times S)$ has positive second fundamental form.

And $G_0 (U\times S)$, homeomorphic to solid torus, has no positive second fundamental form for any ball $U$ (These are obatined from direct computation)

> **Question :** Intuitively, given saddle $F_0$, how can we find saddle $F_\sigma$ s.t. $G_\sigma
> (U_\sigma\times S)$ has a positive second fundamental form ?

**Reference :** On intrinsic geometry of surface in normed spaces  - Burago and Ivanv

[Add]

Exercise (cf. Reference) : Hypersurface has a positive second
fundamental form at $p$ if there is a linear function $L$ and $c>0$
s.t. $L(q)\leq L(p)- c|q-p|^2$ for all $q$ in a neighborhood of $p$

If $ F_0(x,y)=(x,y,\frac{x^2-y^2}{2},xy)$, then $dF_0\ U\times S$
has out normal $W$ at a point $(a,b,0,0),\ (a,b)\in S$.

$ \langle W,(a,b,0,0) -(a_0,b_0,0,0)\rangle \leq -c
 \{ |(a,b)-(a_0,b_0)|^2+|(x,y)|^2\}$ does not hold since there is a
 term $|(x,y)|^2$.

Hence we have a strategy to find $f_\sigma$ s.t. $|
(df_\sigma)_{(x,y)}(a,b) -(a,b)| \leq O(x^2,xy,y^2)
$